# Unioned query result to temp table

Tags: sql-server

I have a subquery which I want to insert into a temp table. But, I get syntax error such as `SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near ')'.`.

```
select *
into #TempTable
from (
        SELECT x,y,z
        FROM 
         schemaA.tableC
        where (x  = '1234')
        UNION 
        SELECT x,y,z
        FROM 
         schemaB.tableC
        where (x  = '1234')
)

select *
from #TempTable
```

Comment: Better question - why do you need a temp table? And do you understand the potentially significant difference between UNION  and UNION ALL?

Comment: @SMor yes sir, union all doesn't remove duplicates in the result. I think to apply group by easily on the temp table.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give an alias to the inner query:

```
select *
into #TempTable
from (
        SELECT x,y,z
        FROM 
         schemaA.tableC
        where (x  = '1234')
        UNION 
        SELECT x,y,z
        FROM 
         schemaB.tableC
        where (x  = '1234')
) AS P

select *
from #TempTable
```

Simply, the structure is:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
   (SELECT * FROM MyTable) AS P
```

Comment: Ha! I type way to slowly.

Answer (score 1):

Add an alias to the derived table and you'll be good to go:

```
select a.*
into #TempTable
from (
        SELECT x,y,z
        FROM 
         schemaA.tableC
        where (x  = '1234')
        UNION 
        SELECT x,y,z
        FROM 
         schemaB.tableC
        where (x  = '1234')
) AS a;

select *
from #TempTable;
```